# How to programmatically disable cells in a Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel

Tags: javascript, combobox, extjs4, cell, tablecell

I have a web application that uses ExtJS 4 that incorporates a Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel.

One of the columns of the Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel has a combobox editor that I would like to disable programmatically when the store loads based on the value of another field in the store.

It seems like this should be pretty simple - but so far nothing seems to work.

When the Grid's store loads, I have a listener to check each row and disable the combobox in index 4 depending on the value of another field.

The only thing that I can't get to work is actually disabling the combobox.

Any suggestions?

Here is the psuedo-code.  Thanks in advance

```
listeners: {
    'load': function(st, records, options) {

        var view = getMyEditorGridPanel().getView();

        for (var i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {             

            if (store.getAt(i).get('setDisabled') === 'Y') {


                //The cell at index 4 has a combobox editor - I CAN'T GET IT TO DISABLE!!
                view.getCell(i,4).setDisabled(true);
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view you have **two different things** you need to manage here:

1. **Cell Styling**, the way a cell looks when not being edited (either is enabled or disabled)
2. **Editor Availability**, how to react when a cell is about to be edited (should be possible to edit the cell)

#### Cell Styling

For the first one I would advice to **provide a style to each cell** in order to make it look disabled, this can be achieved **during rendering time** instead trying to do it when the store loads (*btw nothing ensures you that the grid items have been fully rendered just after getting the load event callback*). You can return a custom class per row **by providing an implementation to** **Ext.grid.ViewView**.[**getRowClass**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-method-getRowClass)

```
viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
            return record.get("disabled") ? "mail-disabled" : "";
        }
    }
```

#### Editor Availability

You will also need to **handle** the **Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditingView**.[**beforeedit**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit) **event** and **provide a custom logic** to determine when the editor will be available

```
 plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        listeners: {
            beforeedit: function(editor, e, eOpts) {                
                return e.record.get("disabled") == false;
            }
        }
    })]
```

You can find a **working example** of both [solutions here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rve), hope it helps to solve your problem.

Comment: I had to change this a little to accommodate I'm guessing a different version of ExtJS, but you definitely put me on the right path.

Comment: I put a getCellEditor in the columnModel.  Thanks again.

Comment: Good to hear it help, which version are you using?

Comment: 4.0.  And actually I was able to get it to work using the CellEditing plugin as well.  I just needed to download the right plugin.